# Why Android WebView blink on HorizontalScrollView?

Tags: android, webview, android-listview, android-webview, horizontalscrollview

I am have to write application that have vertical scrollable rows of tiles and all this
rows a horizontally scrolable. Every tile is html+javascript content.
So I adding multiple ListViews in HorizontalScrollView and inside the
getView method of ListView's BaseAdapter Iam binding WebView.
It is simple scheme:

```
HorizintalScrollView
  LinearLayout
      ListView1 -   WebView1 WebView2.....WebView6    //getView {    WebView.LoadUrl(html)  }  //using with ViewHolder and convertView asking for null
       ...
      ListViewN - WebView....WebView
   /LinearLayout
/HorizontalScrollview
```

Each WebView is too inside linearLayout.
So It is all looks good and works, but when ListView contains more over 5 WebViews each (300 x 300 dip)
and there more then one ListView at HorizontalScrollView all WebViews begin blink (like reloading but without getView) with white color when i try scroll horizontally.

But all ok when i use one ListView. And from some times app crashes. So what the reason??
(in each WebViw I am showing simple interactive highlight html+javascripts chart). I am trying on ASUS Tablet with ICS 4.0
We try do this on iOS by 30 WebViews on ScrollView and there no any problem, all works!
Please explain why blink and crashes app.

Comment: Why WebView blink when i try scroll horizontally? When I scroll vertically one ListView with 50 WebViews all ok and not blink.

Answer (score 1):

Same issue was with me. I tried this solved my problem to a greater Extent

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
            ViewGroup parent) {

        final ViewHolder holder;
        View vi = convertView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.book_reader_list_style, parent,
                    false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.webView = (WebView) vi.findViewById(R.id.webView1);

            holder.webView.setInitialScale(scaleWebView);
            WebSettings webSettings = holder.webView.getSettings();
            holder.webView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
            holder.webView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
            holder.webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
            webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(false);

            vi.setTag(holder);
        } else {

            holder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();
        }
        holder.webView.loadUrl((URLs.get(position)));

        return vi;

    }
```